# How to make an integer in a "while true" loop stop when I write a string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a calculator that asks the user for input until the user writes a string like "stop", then the user has to write an input operation (+,-,etc..).
My main problem is how do I make a user write a string inside an integer input and how do I make another input after the brake?
I have managed to create an infinite loop, how do I replace "i = 0" with "i = "stop"?
If user writes a string it will result in error.

```
i = 0
while True:
    user_input = int("Enter a number: ")
    if user_input = i:
        break
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `input('Enter a number')`? By default that will be a string, so you can check for your stop condition and then you can turn it to an integer with a try statement. The syntax for equality is `==`, not `=`.

Comment: You would probably not want to use `break` in most of the cases. Besides, would it be reasonable to expect that the user always enter a number and an operator alternatively, before the entry ends? If this is the case, then you may want to warn the user to indicate that the number is the last entry.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need them to write "stop" for a specific reason, you can do something like :

```
i = 0
while True:
    print ("Enter a number", end="")
    x = input()
    x = int(x)
    
    # use x as your input number in your calculator.
```

This way, the act of user pressing enter key works as your "stop" check. So the user can input a number. When they press enter, the input is stored in x as string. Then the code converts it into an int.

To parse the keyword stop, you can do

```
x = input()
x = int(x.split("stop")[0].strip())
```

This basically looks for the word "stop" and splits the string from that point. The 0th index should contain the number (assuming the user enters the numbers first followed by "stop"). The .strip() removes white spaces. Finally, we convert this string (that has numbers in it, and no whitespaces) to int.

Comment: I can't use enter as a stop key. I need them to write "stop" and after they write "stop" they need to choose a function (+, -).

Comment: I see, are you allowing users to press Enter at all? For example, would you accept if they enter a number, write stop and then press enter?
Like : 
12345 stop <enter>

If so then you can just parse, like 
x = input()
x = int(x.split("stop")[0].strip())
becomes your number.

Comment: Yes, they may press enter. I will try that.

Comment: I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was running indefinitely because of the "=". When it hits that line, it overrides the current value of user_input with 0, which a conditional statement reads as false, so the 'break' statement will never be reached.

First you must use double "==" instead of one "=" when comparing. You also should check before converting to an int:

```
i = "stop"
while True:
    print("Enter a number: ")
    user_input = input()
    if user_input == i:
        break
    else:
        intInput = int(user_input) #assuming you are checking for int inputs and properly handling type errors
        # you can now use intInput
```

Of course, you can remove "i" and just directly check "if user_input == "stop":" if you'd like